# tinyMCE in cake PHP - plugin CakeDC/TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, cakephp, tinymce

How to set content to tinyMce for editing? I can't find any way to add content in.

in view:

```
echo $this->TinyMCE->editor('vinagro');
echo '<textarea name="data[Article][content]" id="articleContent" class="mceSimple"></textarea>';
```

in bootstrap:

```
Configure::write('TinyMCE.configs', array(
    'vinagro' => array(
        'mode' => 'textareas',
        'theme' => 'advanced',
        'editor_selector' => 'mceSimple',
        'width' => 790,
        'height' => 880,
        'content' => "asdf",
        'skin' => "o2k7",
        'theme_advanced_toolbar_location' => "top",
        'theme_advanced_buttons1' => 'fontselect,separator,bold,italic,underline,separator,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,bullist,numlist,separator,link,image,separator,undo,redo',
        'theme_advanced_buttons2' => '',
        'theme_advanced_buttons3' => '',
        //'plugins' => 'pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,wordcount,advlist,autosave'
    ),
    ));
```

editor will load, but not with content. I tried many ways to add content in. But without result.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I solved it.

I always tried use tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("content"); on document ready. But tinymce in this time is not initialized, so i found window load and it's working.

```
$(window).load(function(){
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent("content");  
})
```